# Microsoft SQL Server: how to put together these three tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a database that is a vault. I have three tables:

**Documents** table - actually file names

```
   DocumentID
   FileName
   a bunch of other columns
```

**Projects** table - actually folder names

```
   ProjectID
   Path
   a bunch of other columns
```

**DocumentsInProjects**:

```
   ProjectID (from Projects)
   DocumentID (from Documents)
```

The `DocumentsInProjects` sample data looks like:

```
ProjectID   DocumentID
----------------------
34           23974
998             28
```

The `DocumentsInProjects` is a table that connects the `Document` to the `Project` (folder) it is in.

I need to do a select that produces the path\FileName. Additionally I need to only show the combination of path/filename where:

- paths contain certain text
- filenames contain certain text

I have no real clue as to how to build this query. It seems like it might be a join but my SQL skills are very, very weak.

Comment: You're looking for an ```INNER JOIN```, notice you can practice your own queries [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join). That's probably why you get downvoted, there are dozens of examples of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables, concatenate the strings and use `LIKE` to look for the "certain text".

```
SELECT p.path + '\' + d.filename
       FROM documents d
            INNER JOIN documentsinprojects dp
                       ON dp.documentid = d.documentid
            INNER JOIN projects p
                       ON p.projectid = dp.projectid
       WHERE p.path LIKE '%certain text%'
             AND d.filename LIKE '%certain text%';
```

Comment: For my own administration: The ```LIKE```keyword is quite slow, or am I saying something stupid? I thought it wasn't a first class query type

Comment: @Rich_Rich: It cannot use indexes if the begin of the "pattern" is variable. But the OP explicitly says "contain certain text". `LIKE '%..%'` is one possibility to search for a string that contains another string.

Comment: @sticky bit - spot on. Thank you so much! I need to look into indexing and using contains. This query will not be used very often though. Speed is not utmost.

Comment: @stickybit so there is no more efficient way to do this without doing so much yourself?